# Jade - Print many variables in one line

Tags: node.js, express, pug, keystonejs

I am trying to print several variables that i have passed from the controller to view in one line.
The content of the variables is like "xyz", where tag is a valid html tag.
What i am doing now is -

```
div
  != (notification.content + notification._.publishedDate.format('MMMM Do, YYYY'))
```

However this prints the div on two lines.
The html content generated is -

```
<div>
    <p>School is closed tomorrow&nbsp;<a href="http://www.booking.com">link</a></p>
     March 7th, 2016
</div>
```

Additionally i cannot do -

```
p= (notification.content + notification._.publishedDate.format('MMMM Do, YYYY'))
```

Because the output is this then in HTML -

```
<p>&lt;p&gt;School is closed tomorrow&amp;nbsp;&lt;a href="http://www.booking.com"&gt;link&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;March 7th, 2016</p>
```

Comment: I'm not realy sure what you are trying to do... You want to concat all the variables on 1 line, with converted html tags, but there are also `<p>` tags in the content? So if you want to have it on on line you need to make sure there are no 'blocked' tags in the notification.content...

Comment: Yes that is the case

Comment: Like I said, make sure there are no <p> tags in the content, or style the div where you concat the variables and set `p{ display: inline-block; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Hey!

See some ways to display your message using Jade/HTML.

Please, test these ways and **use the best** on your project:

---

#### Declaring Variables

```
// Variable with `<p></p>`
- var notification = {content: '<p>School is closed tomorrow <a href="http://www.booking.com">link</a></p>', publishedDate: '2016-03-07'}

// Variable withOUT `<p></p>`
- var test = {content: 'The message <a href="#">link</a>', publishedDate: '2016-03-07'}
```

---

#### 1) Return Escaped Text

```
div #{notification.content} #{notification.publishedDate}

// Return | escaped string:
// <p>School is closed tomorrow <a href="http://www.booking.com">link</a></p> 2016-03-07
```

---

#### 2) Return HTML Code (unescaped | real tags)

```
div !{notification.content} !{notification.publishedDate}

// Return | unescaped (2 lines)
// School is closed tomorrow link
// 2016-03-07
```

---

#### 3) Return HTML Code Inline (unescaped too)

You need modify the array entries. See the var "test" above (on Declaring Variables):

```
div: p !{test.content} !{test.publishedDate}

// Return | unescaped (1 line)
// The message link 2016-03-07
```

---

If works for you, try apply your own variables and rules.
I'm learning about Jade. I hope to help you.

*- Any doubts comment here or talk with me [@devromulobastos](http://www.twitter.com/devromulobastos/)*